Is there a way to convert BACPAC files into a readable format?
We are using BACPAC files for our MS-SQL Server in an Azure elastic pool to create backups.
We faced a problem where while resorting the backup an error with a PK occurred.
Is there a possibility to transform a BACPAC files after unzipping it into a readable format?
Such i can see any data that could lead to a corrupt insert statement.

"A BACPAC file is a ZIP file with an extension of BACPAC containing the metadata and data from the database." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql

BACPACs are not intended to be used for backup and restore operations (from the same link)
